# VisualStudio 2013 DesignMode CurrentDirectory

Tags: visual-studio-2013, path, visual-studio-designer

i have a problem with designer in VS2013. When i'm using

```
Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
```

or

```
Environment.CurrentDirectory;
```

I'm getting path like this one

> C:\Users{username}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\ProjectAssemblies\7qgkktom01\sm_conf.db.xml

when i  running this program in Debug or Release mode then i'm getting the right path.

Comment: Hmm, an .xml file isn't that likely.  But sure, using the [DesignMode property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.component.designmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is important to ensure that your code doesn't do anything inappropriate when it runs at design time.

Comment: I used it but a designer executes the code in brackets `if (! designMode) {...}`